# SQLite3, MATCH and OR

Tags: sqlite, match

Is it valid to combine `MATCH` with `OR`?

For example,

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH 'andrew' OR name MATCH 'bill';`

does not generate any hits, while both

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH 'andrew';` and

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH 'bill';`

do give hits.

%%

Edit. The select with OR error code is 1, so it's malformed some how. The result on the second and third is 0 so they're fine. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH 'andrew OR bill'
```

Comment: 16 SDiz: Thanks for this. Is there a way to mix `MATCH` and `REGEXP`?

Comment: One additional info **match** is available for Virtual Table only, for regular one use ''like".

Comment: How do I match an half word? Suppose I have queried just andr.How do I use pattern for this.

Comment: Was looking for something like this...SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name MATCH '("andrew" OR "drew") OR bill'; per https://sqlite.org/fts3.html#_set_operations_using_the_enhanced_query_syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH 'andrew OR bill'

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH ('andrew' OR 'bill')

c.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name MATCH (? OR ?)", ('andrew', 'bill'))
#safe from SQL injection attacks by escaping the variables.
```

> SQLite understands the following binary operators,
>   in order from highest to lowest precedence:
>
> ```
> ||
> *    /    %
> +    -
> <<   >>   &    |
> <    <=   >    >=
> =    ==   !=   <>   IS   IS NOT   IN   LIKE   GLOB   MATCH   REGEXP
> AND
>
> OR
> ```
>
> Supported unary prefix operators are these:
>
> ```
> -    +    ~    NOT
> ```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: `MATCH (... OR ...)` does not do what you think it does. The whole subexpression is passed to the extension connected to the virtual table, and it'll deal with what was passed in. None of the FTS extensions, nor the spellfix1 extension, support anything other than a single string. The fts extensions support a richer query language *embedded in the string*, and do not use SQLite operators.